# Screencast, SimFinger and "Coudn't find iOS Simulator"

Tags: ios

I'm trying to use SimFinger to make a screencast of my iPhone app. When I launch it I obtain the msg "Couldn't find iOS Simulator".
Actually, I succeed in making the video, but the landscape mode isn't supported (And I need that the "fake" iPhone changes orientation).
I've tried to change @"iOS Simulator" in the FakeFingerAppDelegate.m:

```
if([application.localizedName isEqualToString:@"iOS Simulator"])
{...}
```

but nothing happens.

Any suggestion?
What could I use instead of SimFinger to screencast an app showing it both in portrait and landscape mode, with a cursor like that of SimFinger and with a fake mask?

Comment: Are you using the latest version from https://github.com/atebits/SimFinger ?

Comment: @gcamp: yes, I've downloaded it again today from github

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved thanks to this [link](https://github.com/atebits/SimFinger/issues/10).
It needs to change the name of the iOS Simulator application in the app delegate.